# React navigation goBack() not navigating to the correct screen with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am building an React Native app with Expo using both Tab and Stack Navigator:

if not logged in

- AuthStack

if logged in

- HomeTab

  - HomeList
  - Details
- ChatTab

  - ChatList
  - Message
- ProfileTab

IOS is working perfectly fine, however, the Android is not working *after logging in*. (Android is working fine after reloading the app.)

After logging in, when I navigate to Details from HomeList and click on the button that triggers goBack(), it somehow navigates to ChatTab/ProfileTab. It should navigate back to HomeList. When I click back to the HomeTab, it will still be the Details screen.

After reloading the app, everything becomes working, if I sign out and log back in, the problem arises again.

TabNavigator.js

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ...

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeList">
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeList" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const ChatStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="ChatList">
      <Stack.Screen name="ChatList" component={Chat} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const TabNavigator = () => {

  ...

  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <Tab.Navigator 
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#E59333',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#2E4851',
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
            height: height, // Increase the height of the bottom tab bar
            paddingBottom: paddingBottom,
          },
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: 13,
            fontWeight: '500',
            marginBottom: "2%"
          },
          tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        })}
        backBehavior='none'
      >
        
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeStack}
        />
        
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Chat" 
          component={ChatStack}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfileScreen}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

StackNavigator.js

```
...
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={backButtonOption}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={backButtonOption}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Verify" component={VerifyScreen} options={backButtonOption} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Role" component={RoleScreen} options={backButtonOption} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AboutYou" component={AboutYouScreen} options={backButtonOption} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./config/firebase";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import StackNavigator from './StackNavigator';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';

const AuthenticatedUserContext = createContext({});

const AuthenticatedUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  return (
    <AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  ...

  function RootNavigator () {
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribeAuth = onAuthStateChanged(auth,
        async authenticatedUser => {
          authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      );
        return unsubscribeAuth;
    }, [user]);
    
    if(loading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        { user ? <TabNavigator /> : <StackNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <AuthenticatedUserProvider>
        <RootNavigator /> 
      </AuthenticatedUserProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}
```

I have tried using `navigation.navigate("HomeList")` however it is not working and had the same problem.